# BOINC just will not work

Tags: boinc

I have the issue of "Unable to connect to core client" that others have had in the past and their solutions are not working.

I do not have a firewall running.

The suggestion here has already been carried out by the install script:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/BOINC#Using_BOINC

Apparently the BOINC client is running but this is not reflected in the output of `nmap localhost`.

Nothing works.

Running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, BOINC version is 7.2.42 i686-pc-linux-gnu.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: I uninstalled BOINC and have been using F@H since then. I'll let you know what happens if I attempt to test it now.

Comment: Since I did this uninstall, Ubuntu has a package prepared for BOINC, which is effective. I will accept your answer though I have no way to verify this is my only option anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the terminal:

```
sudo boinc --dir /var/lib/boinc-client
```

If the project is not attached yet, run:

```
sudo boinc --dir /var/lib/boinc-client --attach_project [URL] [KEY]
```

Where `[URL]` can be found in the project list and `[KEY]` is given by logging in in project site or by running after registration:

```
sudo boinc --daemon
sudo boinccmd --lookup_account [URL] [MAIL] [PASSWORD]
```

For instance, for`milkyway@home`, I run `BOINC` with:

```
sudo boinc --dir /var/lib/boinc-client http://milkyway.cs.rpi.edu/milkyway 6c2b64e6238a1223e3a4f8db56eabb3d
```

where my key is obtained using:

```
sudo boinc --daemon
sudo boinccmd --lookup_account http://milkyway.cs.rpi.edu/milkyway/ mymail@address.com mypassword
```

`mymail@adress.com` may be replaced by the username for certain project (including the [worldcommunitygrid](http://www.worldcommunitygrid.org) )